# Module backend parameters not shown in frontend

Tags: php, parameters, module, joomla3.0

My question has not so much to do with the code but more with configuration in Joomla. This because the module I build works perfect on my own website (Joomla 3.4.4 / PHP 5.4.16) but fails to show backend parameters on my customers site (Joomla 3.4.3 / PHP 5.4.44).

To test this I created a test module to check if parameters from the backend are set and to return a message stating they where set or not. With this test I found out that the parameters aren't set on my clients page. But I have no idea why they aren't set. I have tried changing my code to get the parameters and checked out multiple sites on this topic but can't find an answer. I get the feeling this is a configuration issue and would like to know if anybody else has had this issue and how they fixed it.

The main files for this module are listed below.

Hope someone can help me with this cause it's been frustrating me for days now.

Eelco

idealmodule.xml file:

```
<config>
    <fields name="params">
        <fieldset name="basic">
            <field name="class_sufix" type="text" default="" label="Class sufix" />
            <field name="header_text" type="text" default="" label="Header text" />
        </fieldset>
    </fields>
</config>
```

idealmodule.php file:

```
<?php

// No direct access
defined('_JEXEC') or die('Restricted access');

// Include the syndicate functions only once
require_once dirname(__FILE__) . '/helper.php';

$module = JModuleHelper::getModule('mod_idealdonatie');
$moduleParams = new JRegistry($module->params);
$test = ModIdealDonatieHelper::getFormData($moduleParams);
require JModuleHelper::getLayoutPath('mod_idealdonatie');
```

helper.php file:

```
<?php
class ModIdealDonatieHelper
{

public static function getFormData($params)
{
    $var1 = $params->get('class_sufix');
    $var2 = $params->get('header_text');

    if ($var1 != NULL) {
        $mess = 'class_sufix value : ' . $var1;
    } else {
        $mess = 'class_sufix is empty';
    }

    if ($var2 != NULL) {
        $mess = $mess . ' header_text value : ' . $var2;
    } else {
        $mess = $mess . ' header_text is empty';
    }

    return $mess;
}
}
```

and default.php

```
<?php 
defined('_JEXEC') or die('Restricted access');
echo $test;
?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seemed to be an issue with the website configuration.